When is an operator invertible equivalent to a positive operator?
Let $T$ be an invertible operator and $P,Q$ be positive operators such that $T^*PT \leq Q \leq P$. Is it true that $Q$ is of the form $S^*PS$ for some invertible operator $S$?
Since $0\leq Q \leq P$, from the famous Douglas' lemma we get $Q^{\frac{1}{2}}=P^{\frac{1}{2}} S$ which will give us $Q=(Q^{\frac{1}{2}})^*(Q^{\frac{1}{2}}) = S^*PS$. But this $S$ need not be invertible. So, we need to use the property that $Q$ is not just positive but $Q \geq T^*PT$ for some invertible $T$.
For example, if T is a scalar multiple of identity operator, then what we have is $\alpha P \leq Q \leq P$. Then by Douglas' lemma, we get $Range(P^{\frac{1}{2}}) = Range(Q^{\frac{1}{2}})$. Now, we can use the fact that two positive operators have same range if and only if they differ by an invertible operator. Therefore, $Q^{\frac{1}{2}} = P^{\frac{1}{2}} S$ for some invertible operator $S$. Then $Q=(Q^{\frac{1}{2}})^*(Q^{\frac{1}{2}}) = S^*PS$.
But I am not able to prove this for general invertible operator $T$.
Thanks in advance for any help.

At least the $S$ given by Douglas’ lemma cannot work. There are examples in which we even have $Q = T^\ast PT$ but any $S$ with $Q^{1/2} = P^{1/2}S$ cannot be invertible. (For example, on $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$, with $P$ being the projection onto $\overline{\text{span}}{e_n}_{n \geq 0}$ and $T$ being the leftward bilateral shift.)

Yes. That's a good observation. Thank you.

Here is a counterexample:
Let $H = l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $P$ be the projection onto $\overline{\text{span}}\{e_n\}_{n \geq 0}$. Let $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ be the bijection defined by,
$$\phi(n) = \begin{cases}
\frac{n}{2} &, n < 0 \text{ and } n \text{ is even}\\
-n &, n < 0 \text{ and } n \text{ is odd}\\
2n &, n \geq 0
\end{cases}$$
Let $T$ be defined by $Te_n = e_{\phi^{-1}(n)}$, then it is easy to check that $T^\ast PT$ is the projection onto $\overline{\text{span}}\{e_{2n}\}_{n \geq 0}$. Let $Q$ be defined by,
$$Qe_n = \begin{cases}
0 &, n < 0\\
e_n &, n \geq 0 \text{ and } n \text{ is even}\\
\frac{1}{n}e_n &, n \geq 0 \text{ and } n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$$
Then we have $T^\ast PT \leq Q \leq P$. However, $Q$ cannot be written as $S^\ast PS$ for any invertible $S$. Indeed, if $Q = S^\ast PS$, then as $S$ is invertible, we have $\text{range}(Q) = S^\ast(\text{range}(P))$. As $S^\ast$ is invertible as well and $P$ has closed range, we must have the range of $Q$ is closed. But it is not. Indeed, for any $N \geq 0$, $\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{2n+1}e_{2n+1} \in \text{range}(Q)$, but $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2n+1}e_{2n+1} \notin \text{range}(Q)$.

Yes, this works. Thanks a lot!
